# How can I mock a abastract class or interface in Python using - testing with pytest

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, pytest, testunit

I create an interface to provide email validation for my controller

```
class EmailValidatorInterface(ABC):
    """ Interface to EmailValidator use case """

    @abstractmethod
    def is_valid(self, email: str) -> bool:
        """ Specific case """

        raise Exception("Should implement method: is_valid")
```

That is my controller implementation

```
class SignUpController(RouteInterface):
    def __init__(self, emailValidator: EmailValidatorInterface):
        self.emailValidator = emailValidator

    def route(self, http_request: Type[HttpRequest]) -> HttpResponse:
```

How can I create a mock for my EmailValidator?
I'm trying to use mock.patch but I don't how to initialize the mock

Look at my test

```
def test_should_return_400_if_invalid_param_is_provided():

    with mock.patch('EmailValidatorStub') as MockEmailValidator:
        MockEmailValidator.return_value.is_valid.return_value = False

    sut = SignUpController(EmailValidatorStub())
    attributes = {
        "name": faker.word(),
        "login": faker.word(),
        "email": "any_email",
        "email_confirmation": "any_email@mail.com",
        "password": "any_password",
        "password_confirmation": "any_password"
    }

    request = HttpRequest(body=attributes)
    httpResponse = sut.route(request)
    assert httpResponse.status_code == 500
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you need `mock.patch` here since you can just use dependency injection. In other words, just create a subclass like you normally would, but add implementation that is specific to the test:

```
class MockValidator(EmailValidatorInterface):
   pass
```

Then instantiate it in your test:

```
sut = MockValidator()
```

You can either create a separate mock class for each scenario you are testing or add a `__init__()` method that takes parameters that can vary between each scenario. Or some combination of the two. Mocks shouldn't contain any logic but instead just satisfy a specific scenario that is tested.

Comment: Hi, 
That makes sense. I could create a stub class
EmailValidatorStub(EmailValidatorInterface):
I concern about it,
in order to resolve multiples scenarios...I would add logic into this stub class because in some scenarios it should return true and in some cases, it should return false. Is it right? I mean, add logic in the stub class? I'm trying to this project with a Clean-Architecture approach.
Ok, I know that I also can create more than one or two stub classes to support that scenario...I just don't if it's a good practice.

Comment: @user428745 Mocks should have minimal logic. A third option here is to pass in values to `__init__()` for the scenario of a given test.